# Undefined numeric links in slider

Tags: jquery, slider, numeric

i have a jquery slider,
link: http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/

this is my html code:

```
<div id="features">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

Slider Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#features').jshowoff({
  speed:3500,
  changeSpeed:400,
  links: false,
  animatePause: true,
  controls: true,
  effect: 'slideLeft',
  controlText:{play:'Play',pause:'Stop',previous:'Prev',next:'Next'},
  hoverPause: true 
 });                
});
</script>
```

everything is work in my slider except numeric links!

if i enable it:

```
links: true,
```

i will get undefined code!
it should be 1  2  3
not undefined undefined undefined

look to my picture pls:

http://s7.postimage.org/buf1wehsr/sliders.jpg

How i can fix numeric links?
i hope u guys undrstand me, sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but looking at the examples on the site, their links are placed in anchor tags -> `<a>`. Maybe try that?

Comment: no its not working like that, i copied all the codes frome author site, but its same problem!

Comment: Try putting some more stuff inside the `<div>` tags: from the site: `<div><p>This is a slide!</p></div>`, because it seems to imply that you don't need to name them yourself. Supplying `links: true` should do it automatically.

Comment: sorry but its not working again! i dont know what should i do now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="features">
    <div title="1">1</div>
    <div title="2">2</div>
    <div title="3">3</div>
</div>
```